# Java Layout not showing components (sometimes)

Tags: java, swing, components, boxlayout

I'm writing a MathQuiz for my pupils including JLatexMath for rendering and jinput for the buzzers. The problem is, that sometimes (like every fourth time) when I start the program, none of the components are visible. They appear after resizing the JFrame. 
First I was thinking of Bugs in the jinput or jlatexMath libraries, but I do get the same Error even with this minimal Code:

```
public class Shell extends JFrame{

  private JButton button1;
  private JButton button2;
  private Formula formula;

  public Shell() {
    super("blaBla");
    this.setSize(800, 600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    Box b = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    button1 = new JButton(" ");
    button1.setEnabled(false);
    b.add(button1);
    b.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    button2 = new JButton(" ");
    button2.setEnabled(false);
    b.add(button2);
    add(b);
    JPanel formulaPanel = new JPanel();
    add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
    add(formulaPanel);
  } 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Shell s = new Shell();
  }
}
```

What is wrong, with the code?

Comment: Well, if you have weird problems with Swing, it's best to heed the docs and make sure all [Swing code is executed on the Event Dispatch Thread.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)  Start there.

Comment: Ok, thx for the quick answer.
When I add 
   System.out.println(javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
to the Constructor I get false on the console. How can I make my Thread the EventDispatchThread?

Comment: There's several links on the left of that link I gave you.  It's best to read ALL the documentation, otherwise who knows what you missed.  [Try this link,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) but you do need to read that whole section on concurrency in Java.  At least.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the links :-) 
I already found out, that the creation of the JFrame should look like this:
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          new Shell();
      }
  });
but I'll keep reading...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by moving `setVisible(true);` to the end of the constructor.

Instead of been here...

```
public Shell() {
    super("blaBla");
    this.setSize(800, 600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    //...
}
```

Move it here...

```
public Shell() {
    super("blaBla");
    //...
    add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
    add(formulaPanel);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

To protect against any other possible graphical glitches, you should always start you UI's from within the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: setVisible at the end of the constructor seems to work fine so far. 
Thanks for your help :-)